# Update Data Using Multiselect Sequelize(mysql) in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize include using this command **Complaint.belongsTo(Store);**

and iam getting the **req.body** as:

```
req.body===========> { id: 2,
  cno: 100,
  dt: '2017-07-25T20:49:36.000Z',

  cname: 'feugiat',
  product: 'posuere at, velit. Cras lorem lorem, luctus ut, pellentesque',
  brand: 'lobortis quam a felis',
  shop: '$2a$10$J4taP8HVULiBaLE51o8QW.hYG6VUUjxzCpoDnoYDFAXWjmUbGexja',
  status: 'Unassigned',
  rid: 1,
  cmbno: '(234) 341-9792',
  cemail: 'velit@convallisestvitae.org',
  desc: 'cursus. Integer mollis. Integer tincidunt aliquam arcu. Aliquam ultrices iaculis',
  req: null,
  isActive: true,
  activity: '2018-04-11T06:23:34.000Z',
  createdAt: '2017-05-27T03:40:27.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2018-10-07T20:56:20.000Z',
  adminId: null,
  storeId: [ 14, 15, 16 ],
  serviceId: null,
  admin: null,
  store: null,
  service: null }
```

I am getting the **storeId** value as **storeId: [ 14, 15, 16 ]**.

Then i am getting the server side error => **POST /api/needrequest/:id 400** ,

my api:

```
exports.needRequest = function(req, res) {
    console.log('the data===========>',req.body);
    Complaint.update(req.body, {
        where: {
            id: req.body.id
        }
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log('include', req.body);
        Complaint.findAll({
            where: {
                id: req.params.id
            },
            include: [{
                model: Admin,
            }, {
                model: Store,
            }, {
                model: Service,
            }]
        })
    }).then(function(data) {
        return res.status(200).send(data);
    }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function(err) {
        return res.status(422).send(err.errors[0].message);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    });
};
```

How Can i Update this?

Please give any solution!

Comment: you need to get the store object. Fetch the stores with ids mentioned in array and the use the setter method.

Comment: can you post some piece of code!